# Invalid controller class: display

Tags: component, joomla-4.x

I am trying to create a simple component. After installation of the component I get the following error message in the admin view:

```
An error has occurred.
0 Invalid controller class: display
```

I've already seen [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32548/joomla-4-invalid-controller-classdisplay) question from another user but adding the `<namespace>`-tag didn't solve the error.

###### mycomponent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="1.0.0" type="component">
    <name>MyComponent</name>
    <namespace path="src">Firecase\Component\MyComponent</namespace>
    <administration>
        <menu>MyComponent</menu>
        <files folder="admin">
            <folder>services</folder>
            <folder>src</folder>
            <folder>tmpl</folder>
        </files>
    </administration>
</extension>
```

###### DisplayController.php

```
<?php
namespace Firecase\Component\MyComponent\Administrator\Controller;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;

class DisplayController extends BaseController
{
    protected $default_view = 'mycomponent';

    public function display($cachable = true, $urlparams = array())
    {
        return parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);
    }
}
?>
```

###### provider.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\ComponentInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\MVCComponent;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\Service\Provider\ComponentDispatcherFactory;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\Service\Provider\MVCFactory;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Factory\MVCFactoryInterface;
use Joomla\DI\Container;
use Joomla\DI\ServiceProviderInterface;

return new class implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $container): void {
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new MVCFactory('\\Firecase\\Component\\MyComponent'));
        $container->registerServiceProvider(new ComponentDispatcherFactory('\\Firecase\\Component\\MyComponent'));
        $container->set(
            ComponentInterface::class,
            function (Container $container) {
                $component = new MVCComponent($container->get(ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface::class));
                $component->setMVCFactory($container->get(MVCFactoryInterface::class));

                return $component;
            }
        );
    }
}
?>
```

###### directory structure

```
com_mycomponent
├─ admin
│  ├─ services
│  │  └─ provider.php
│  ├─ src
│  │  ├─ controller
│  │  │  └─ DisplayController.php
│  │  ├─ model
│  │  └─ view
│  │     └─ mycomponent
│  │        └─ HtmlView.php
│  └─ tmpl
│     └─ mycomponent
│        └─ default.php
├─ site
│  └─ src
│     ├─ controller
│     ├─ model
│     └─ view
└─ mycomponent.xml
```

Comment: File name DisplayController.php maybe?

Comment: most probably a typo in the provider.php file, that can cause this invalid diplay controller error. Please check that file or copy the content of provider.php file here in your question

Comment: @Peli - I mean, you are right basically, according to the PSR standards, filename must match the casing of the terminating class name, but as I tested that in Joomla4, if you name the controller file with lower cases, that does not raise or cause this error for some reasons. However, if you reference that for example in provider.php with wrong casing, that causes this error.

Comment: @Zollie, thank you for the response. I've added the content of my provider.php above.

Comment: And have you re-installed this component after correcting the namespaces?

Comment: @Zollie, I've re-installed the component and deleted the Joomla! cache.

Comment: I have copied your code into my test component files and it worked without problems, I do not see at the moment anything problematic in your updated code., other than already suggested here by me and others and repaired.... strange

Comment: I can only imagine that you have a new error message now, that html view is not found or something of that sort… the display controller looks OK now.

Comment: @Zollie, I'll try to install my component on a new Joomla! installation. Maybe that will change something.

Comment: @Zollie, installing my component on a local Joomla! installation works fine. But as soon as I try to install it on a hosted Joomla! installation the same error appears.

Comment: Both of the are the same version of Joomla 4? Something to do with the hosting server... I do not have a clue on this now. The component is working for sure.

Comment: @Zollie, both of them are the same Joomla! version. I also tried installing my component on different hosting servers and the error occured on all of them.

Comment: Version Joomla 4.2.8 on PHP 8.2 ?

Comment: Any update on this? Was the issue solved? How?

Comment: A short explanation of this issue is known a long time ago, on deploying different OS, but here a developer Nickolas K. summarized it: Folder and file name case matters. You may not notice it when developing on a Windows or macOS machine with a case-insensitive filesystem but you will definitely suffer if you mix it up when deploying your component on a Linux-based server where the filesystem is virtually guaranteed to be case-sensitive. https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/com-views.html

Comment: @Zollie, sadly I didn't find a solution yet. Joomla and PHP version all all up to date. I will continue developing and testing my component locally (where the error doesn't occur), but sooner or later it has to work. So I will keep looking for solutions.

Comment: @firecase, could you provide a screen shot of your directory structure of the component for us to look at? In each case where I have seen the same message when moving to a live *nix server from a local  dev environment on windows the issues has always been a problem with the case of a directory, a  file name or namespace entry so I am thinking we need to see more of your structure to assist you further

Answer (score 1):

You have a lowercase 'f' in firecase, it should be Firecase. Namespaces in Joomla are very particular about having the first character of each level as an uppercase.

And you have a path of "src/", it is most likely you only need to use "src".

Comment: Good point - Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps. and follow psr-4 standards
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: I've tried changing the namespace and `src/` to `src`. Unfortunately it didn't fix the error.

Comment: I just checked one of my provider.php files and I don't have the ": void" in mine, could this be the problem? `public function register(Container $container) {`

Comment: @GlennArkell, I checked a couple of my provider.php files and they don't have the :void statement either.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following

```
<namespace path="src">Firecase\Component\MyComponent</namespace>
```

to

```
<namespace path="src/">Firecase\Component\MyComponent</namespace>
```

Adding the slash may fix the path attribute to the correct path.

Also check

```
<extension version="1.0.0" type="component">
```

Have you tried changing it to

```
<extension type="component" method="upgrade">
```

ADDED:

I  ran into same problem. In my case some of Joomla's core methods were overridden. Try updating your Joomla in the Dashboard and then "Upload and Update".

Comment: `src` with or without the slash does not seem to matter, I have installed components both ways without problems.

Comment: I see. And the xml tag? I know I had problems with `<extension version="1.0.0" type="component">` at a time. But still. Invalid display controller usually is some silly Namespace error from my own experience.

Comment: The xml tag is not really connected to the problem in the question. Yes, most probably Namespace problems in the files.

Comment: Ironically I installed a component update, and now I have the same error too xD.

Comment: It happens with many of us some times :)

Comment: @Zollie. Turns out I override some joomla core methods.. ^^.

so I fixed it using the Joomla updater to re-update the core files.